# Clang compilation errors

Tags: header, clang

Is there any way to let `clang` ignore errors when compiling the code? Such as the missing header errors.

I am using `-emit-llvm` option of `clang` to compile some programs to `llvm` bitcode, however, I don't care if some `header` file is missing.

Comment: If you compile in a pre-c99 mode, you'll get away with implicit function definitions, but it won't handle missing constants, etc. Trying to compile a non-conforming program is probably the beginning of a bad idea...

Comment: But if I just want to do some sort of `program analysis`, which means I need to first translate the program into `llvm IR`, then there is nothing I can do...

Comment: But what does it mean to translate an incomplete/nonconforming program?

Comment: Very few errors can be "ignored" and have the parsing/semantic analysis process continue (more or less correctly). Other errors are totally unrecoverable so this is a broad question.